# Concatenate tuples

Tags: c++, c++11

I've written a (bad) function for unpacking `tuple`s.

```
  template<class tuple_head_t, size_t... HeadIndices, class tuple_tail_t, size_t... TailIndices>
  decltype(auto) concat_tuples_concat(tuple_head_t&& head, index_sequence<HeadIndices...>, tuple_tail_t&& tail, index_sequence<TailIndices...>) noexcept {
    return make_tuple(get<HeadIndices>(forward<tuple_head_t>(head))..., get<TailIndices>(forward<tuple_tail_t>(tail))...);
  }


  template<class tuple_t, class... tuple_ts>
  decltype(auto) concat_tuples(tuple_t&& t1, tuple_ts&&... ts) noexcept {
    return concat_tuples_concat(
      forward<tuple_t>(t1),
      make_index_sequence<tuple_size<remove_reference_t<tuple_t>>::value>(),
      concat_tuples(forward<tuple_ts>(ts)...),
      make_index_sequence<tuple_size<decltype(concat_tuples(forward<tuple_ts>(ts)...))>::value>()
    );
  }


  template<>
  decltype(auto) concat_tuples<>() noexcept {
    return make_tuple();
  }
```

It throws a compile time error.

```
error: template-id ‘concat_tuples<>’ for ‘decltype(auto) sprincle::concat_tuples()’ does not match any template declaration
   decltype(auto) concat_tuples<>() noexcept {
                  ^
```

I smell that compiler has a problem with the return type. The two `decltype(auto)`s evaluate to different types and so the specialization doesn't work. I've since found out that there's a standard library function that concatenates tuples `tuple_cat`. I tried to look into the implementation (GCC 5.2.0)to find out how the return types get deduced, but it's too cryptic for me to understand.

If you happen to know how to do this, would you mind sharing?

Comment: @TartanLlama yes, I was implementing it then I looked up cpprefence.com and found out that is in he std library. Still I'm curious how the return types are taken care of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your empty case is trying to provide a full specialization for a template declaration which doesn't exist (the declared primary template takes at least one argument). Rather than making the empty case a full template specialization, just make it a separate overload and define it above the recursive case:

```
decltype(auto) concat_tuples() noexcept {
  return make_tuple();
}

template<class tuple_t, class... tuple_ts>
decltype(auto) concat_tuples(tuple_t&& t1, tuple_ts&&... ts) noexcept {
  return concat_tuples_concat(
    forward<tuple_t>(t1),
    make_index_sequence<tuple_size<remove_reference_t<tuple_t>>::value>(),
    concat_tuples(forward<tuple_ts>(ts)...),
    make_index_sequence<tuple_size<decltype(concat_tuples(forward<tuple_ts>(ts)...))>::value>()
  );
}
```